# Spring security configuration error for admin request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to configure my Spring application to have a pretty basic security system with Spring security.
I would like to have resources to be served without security filters, standard pages to be filtered checking if the user has the role "User" and /admin/ pages to be served checking if the role is "Admin".

What I have is:

springSecurityFilterChain
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

in the web.xml, while the spring-security.xml is:

```
<security:http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/welcome" logout-url="/logout" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/FormLogin"
        default-target-url="/welcome"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="hashPwd" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
   <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="controlloUtente">
     <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />  
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="controlloUtente"
    class="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.utility.SpringSecurityServiceImpl">
</beans:bean>
```

Then I configured this class:

```
package org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.utility;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Utente;
import org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.dao.UtenteDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class SpringSecurityServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UtenteDaoImpl utenteDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Utente utente = utenteDao.getUtenteByUsername(username);
        if(utente == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("L'utente inserito non è stato trovato");
        }
        return convertUtente(utente);
    }

    private UserDetails convertUtente(Utente utente) {
        UserDetails ud = new User(utente.getUsername(), utente.getHashPwd(), true, true, true, true, getRoles(utente));
        return ud;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getRoles(Utente utente) {
        GrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(utente.getRuolo().getNome());
        List<GrantedAuthority> listaAuth = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        listaAuth.add(auth);
        return listaAuth;
    }

}
```

and the following one:

```
package org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.utility;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DefaultRolesPrefixPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        if(bean instanceof Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) {
            ((Jsr250MethodSecurityMetadataSource) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix("");
        }
        if(bean instanceof DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) {
            ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix("");
        }
//        if(bean instanceof DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) {
//            ((DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler) bean).setDefaultRolePrefix("");
//        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

But nothing works.
My formLogin doesn't use spring forms but a classic form.

When I'm logged in and I try to get a pge like `/admin/testpage`, I get redirected to FormLogin page, even if I have admin role, and this is the debug output:

```
22/06/2015 10:03:04 - DEBUG - (AntPathRequestMatcher.java:141) - Request '/admin/formregistrazione' matched by universal pattern '/**'
22/06/2015 10:03:04 - DEBUG - (HttpSessionRequestCache.java:43) - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/Fantacalcio/admin/FormRegistrazione]
22/06/2015 10:03:04 - DEBUG - (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:202) - Calling Authentication entry point.
22/06/2015 10:03:04 - DEBUG - (DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:39) - Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/Fantacalcio/FormLogin'
22/06/2015 10:03:04 - DEBUG - (HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:337) - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
```

Sometimes, after login, I get this message:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

What did I do wrong? I ALWAYS have to use the token? And why the flow never goes into the SpringSecurityServiceImpl class?

Thanks

EDIT: I disabled `csrf` and it's getting clear now. The problem is in my `SpringSecurityServiceImpl` the `Autowired` utenteDao instance is null. I edited the spring-security.xml file like this, hoping Spring understands the `@Service` annotated class but it doesn't work:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="SpringSecurityServiceImpl">
         <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />  
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

My UtenteDao class

```
package org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.beans.Utente;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UtenteDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<Utente> implements UtenteDao{

     public UtenteDaoImpl() {
    System.out.println("test");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Utente> trovaUtentiAttivi(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class).add(Restrictions.eq("attivo", true)).list();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Utente getUtenteFromCredenziali(Utente utente){
        List<Utente> utenteTrovato = getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("username", utente.getUsername()))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("hashPwd", utente.getHashPwd()))
                .list();
        Utente utenteLoggato = utenteTrovato.size() == 0 ? null : utenteTrovato.get(0);
        return utenteLoggato;
    }

    public Boolean usernameExists(String username){
        return getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username))
                .list().size() > 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Utente getUtenteByUsername(String username){
        List<Utente> utenteTrovato = getSession().createCriteria(Utente.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("username", username))
                .list();
        Utente utenteLoggato = utenteTrovato.size() == 0 ? null : utenteTrovato.get(0);
        return utenteLoggato;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why cant I see any CSRF config in your securityApplicationContext.xml?

Comment: I asked, should I mandatory use csrf tokens?

Comment: Actually no, and I cannot see where you are configuring CSRF, so you shouldn't get that error. But because you have that error, you have enable CSRF eventhough by default its enabled.

Comment: Or in your atConfiguration file, you can put  .csrf().disable(); for configure method.

Comment: In Spring Security 4 csrf protection is enabled by default, in earlier versions it was optional (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2347). So yes you need that in all your forms, or disable CSRF protection.

Comment: that's clear, also if I couldn't still find a way to disable it via xml config file, but why I don't always get that message and I often get simply redirected to Login page?

Comment: I disabled it but I got some new issues, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security login and logout forms expect CSRF tokens to be sent in the post request. You can add the token using hidden variable:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Add above line in spring security login form. And logout is also need to be a `post` request method. Every post request to server is gonna check for these tokens which you can set into request header. If you don't want to do this and disable csrf token security.
You can disable it using `csrf` tag in http section of security config. `csrf` has attribute to disable it.

```
<http>
    <csrf />
</http>
```

Read [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/) to know more.

**EDIT:**

You have mentioned `user-service-ref="SpringSecurityServiceImpl"` in security authentication tag but `Service` class does not have an identifier. Give your service class an identifier, prefer camel case characters.

```
@Service("springSecurityServiceImpl") // talking about this identifier
@Transactional
public class SpringSecurityServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {}
```

And authentication provider bean should be:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
   <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="springSecurityServiceImpl">
     <security:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />  
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And also check if your DAO class is marked as `@Repository` component for autowire to work perfectly.

Comment: Adding that to the xml configuration file doesn't disable csrf protection, and I can't find a way to do it by xml.

Comment: What exactly did you add? Can you paste it here. It should be something like <csrf disabled="true" /> .

Comment: I disabled it but I got some new issues, I edited the question.

Comment: I tried with no luck. If I don't define the bean in the xml I always get error with bean not found, if I declare it in the xml the bean is created twice and I get a null dao object.

Comment: I updated it, but the problem is the SpringSecurityServiceImpl is not created even if it's annotated! If I declare that bean it gets created twice and the dao object is null (but when I use my service classes autowired daos are correctly created!)

Comment: Does your <context:component-scan base-package="org.your.package" /> tag covers packages inwhich service and dao classes are declared?

Comment: I have `<context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio" />` that is the main package containing all other packages.

Comment: I solved the problem and posted the answer. I thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. 
Searching around I found out that security and servlet have different context, so basically I had to add the `<context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.utility, org.fabrizio.fantacalcio.model.dao" />`
 on the `security-config.xml` file too, declaring only the package to scan to make the security work, as it doesn't share the beans declared in the dispatcher config file.